# Ng2-charts Bar Chart

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I created a bar chart with ng2 chart. Every columns inside A1. How can I seperate? You can reach here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-chart?file=src/app/app.component.ts

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options, which depend on what you are trying to show

Option 1 ([working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-chart-first-option?file=src/app/app.component.ts)):
data points belong to different elements (apples, oranges, melons):

```
this.barChartData = [
  {
    data: [4900, 0, 0],
    label: "A1",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(180, 0, 0, 1)"
  },
  {
    data: [0, 5500, 0],
    label: "A2",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(33, 81, 255, 1)"
  },
  {
    data: [0, 0, 4800],
    label: "A3",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 166, 0, 1)"
  }
];

this.barChartLabels = ["A1", "A2", "A3"];
```

Option 2 ([working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-chart-second-option?file=src/app/app.component.ts)):
all three data points belong to the same type of element (apples):
they should all appear in the same array for data:

```
this.barChartData = [
    {
      data: [4900, 5500, 4800],
      backgroundColor: ["green", "pink", "yellow"]
    }
];

this.barChartLabels = ["A1", "A2", "A3"];
```

Comment: I want to do as Option 1 you gave 0 I dont want to give 0 is there another to show? Before I used chartJS same chart and same method but I can't get same chart with ng2

Comment: Just I want to make group

Comment: There is undefined label can you show A1, A2 and A3 on label

Comment: its not possible under the same group

Comment: I understand thanks is there another way?

Comment: only if you lose the bottom x axis labels - `this.barChartLabels = ["x axis"];` and keep the rest like your original code

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 working but there is a label problem I want to make such as

[image]